# Wix FileSearch is not returning true for an existing file

Tags: windows, wix

I'm using the following FileSearch in my Bootstrapper (Wix 3.9 version), and it always returns false, even when the file exists:

```
<Wix xmlns="htttp://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
...
<Fragment>
<util:FileSearch Path="%systemdrive%\SomeFile.txt" Varialbe="FileExists" Result="exists"/>
...
```

The log file has the following line:

> File search: *******(some random guid), did not find path: %systemdrive%\SomeFile.txt 
>   Setting numeric variable 'FileExists' to value 0

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not quite so easy to use a runtime environment variable in that way. You first need to set a WiX property with the environment variable and *then* use that WiX property inside your Path attribute. So something like this (note the single `%` prefix):

```
<SetProperty Id="PROP_SYSTEM_DRIVE" Before="InstallInitialize" Sequence="execute" Value="[%SYSTEMDRIVE]" />
```

Then you should be able to use it in your FileSearch:

```
<util:FileSearch Path="[PROP_SYSTEM_DRIVE]\SomeFile.txt" Variable="FileExists" Result="exists"/>
```